# Periodic task and notifications when the application is closed

Tags: android, service, notifications

I have been looking for the best way to execute a periodic task every 30/60 seconds which connects to a web service and show a notification depending on the response. This periodic task should keep on executing even if the application is closed (After Destroy).

I have seen these options:

- **WorkManager:** but the minimum time for this is 15 minutes.
- **AlarmManager:** I have read that the resources consumption would be high for my task frequency.
- **Foreground Service:** This could be a good option but I don't like the constantly shown notification in this mode.

Are there any other optimal option to resolve this? Which one do you recommend me?

Comment: If possible, do the checks on the server side and send a push notification when the conditions are met.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try with Firebase and PHP on server side.